# Import downloaded python package

Tags: python, pip

CloudFunctions does not support private dependencies.
Following their recommendation (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies) I downloaded the package via:

```sh
pip install -t vendor foo
touch vendor/__init__.py
```

Which results in a directory:

```
vendor
|- foo-0.0.1.dist-info
   |- INSTALLER
   |- METADTA
   |- RECORD
   |- REQUESTED
   |- top_level.txt
   |- WHEEL
|- __init__.py
```

Now trying to `import vendor.foo` results in an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vendor.foo
```

Is there an import subtlety I am missing or how is this supposed to work?

Comment: Couple questions: (1) have you checked that you are using the same Python interpreter to which you installed your package? If you are not using a virtualenv and you are using the python3 interpreter you may need to install using pip3. (2) What is in __init__.py?

Comment: _have you checked that you are using the same Python interpreter to which you installed your package?_ yes

Comment: _What is in init.py_ You mean `vendor/__init__.py`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was markdown taking over `__init__.py`

Comment: `vendor/__init__.py` is empty

Comment: Okay, what was the output of your pip install? Curious about how it built the wheels.

Comment: AFAIU the wheel is prebuilt - it just downloads it. So the question is rather whether Python import magic has some way of magically knowing that `dist-info` shall be a package.

Comment: I wouldn't think so. But, I honestly don't know. Sorry, man.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

- relative imports, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python), also the guide you linked uses relative imports. If you import as `import vendor.foo` it will only work if you run the python script in the folder, where also the 'vendor' folder is.
- adding the package location to PYTHONPATH environment variable. `export PYTHONPATH = $PYTHONPATH":/path/to/vendor`. This can also be done inside a python script using `sys.path`. I'm not sure how this is done in case of Gcloud
- installing the package to a virtual environment. As shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup) you can setup a virtual environment. One you activated this you should be able to pip install packages to it.

First approach should definatly work for you.

Comment: _also the guide you linked uses relative import_ As far as I can see quite the contrary - it uses absolute imports.

Comment: _it will only work if you run the python script in the folder, where also the 'vendor' folder is._ Yes and that is exactly my situation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `foo`. Forgot a toplevel `__init__.py`, package autodetection failed and it added no sources to the wheel.

Thus when downloading later, it created no package directory.